# Is it acceptable to create an SKShapeNode in update delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, device-orientation, skshapenode

I create an `SKShapeNode` in `SpriteKit's` `update` `delegate` and it works exactly as I want it to. My only concern is that `update` is called every tenth of a second. Does that mean that my code is also run that often? That doesn't seem very performance friendly. Is there a way around it? Or is it fine having the code on `update`?

Why is the code in `update` in the first place you might ask. Well if I put it in `didMove` or `sceneDidLoad` then when I rotate the `device` the `node` doesn't follow along instantly, it remains in its old place for half a second before relocating to its new position, making it look like it jumps. Bad. `Update` solves this. Here's the code:

```
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        let mySquare = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        mySquare.fillColor = SKColor.blue
        mySquare.lineWidth = 1

        mySquare.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.addChild(mySquare)
    }
}
```

Comment: “Or is it fine” How could it be fine to add a new child every tenth of a second?

Comment: the update func is part of SpriteKit's game loop it is not a delegate. like I told you on your other account @MarcTornej

Comment: You are not solving your problem in the correct way.  Rotation should not be causing your nodes to move.  I would recommend using a square scene if you plan on supporting both orientations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create. the only issue you have is it's creating a new node each time update is called. At the moment you can not see multiple nodes because you're positioning them on top of each other if you try to change the position of **mySquare** on each update call you will see that you have multiple nodes. created which is not effective soon you will run out of frame rates. as you don't have any animations on going you don't see the difference now.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    let mySquare = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    mySquare.fillColor = SKColor.blue
    mySquare.lineWidth = 1

    mySquare.position = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)
    self.addChild(mySquare)
}
```

changing the position of the X and Y will give you the chance to see the nodes being added to different position on the screen.

if for any reason you want to create your mySquare node in the **update** then you can keep a reference for the node or search the node in the parent node if it's available then don't add any

```
var mySquare: SKShapeNode
```

Then in the update check if your Square node is not nil or has the same

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if mySquire == nil {
      mySquare = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
      mySquire.name = "your square name"
      mySquare.fillColor = SKColor.blue
      mySquare.lineWidth = 1

       mySquare.position = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)
       self.addChild(mySquare)
   }
}
```

Note: you can even check for the name like

```
if mySquare.name == "your square name"
```

then don't add it any more

Comment: Big thanks for the info! Any idea how to solve the jumping square issue? Not sure how to deal with that one or why it happens in the first place.

Comment: I think did load has not yet calculate the right or final frame for view by the time it’s called

Answer (score 1):

Doing anything on the **update** func is a bad idea

Apple Documentation:

> Do not call this method directly; it is called by the system exactly once per frame, so long as the scene is presented in a view and is not paused. This is the first method called when animating the scene, before any actions are evaluated and before any physics are simulated.

If you want to create objects and control them, you should use **didMove** func for example. And you can create an action like this **for example**:

```
self.run(
    SKAction.repeatForever(
        SKAction.customAction(withDuration: 0.0, actionBlock: { (_, _) in
            // Create and add new node...
        })
    )
)
```

But probably create a several nodes infinitely is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the info, any idea how to solve the issue with the jumping square?

Comment: I really don't understand the jumping square issue. That's can be for another reason, like the present scene again. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60542976/spritekit-layout-lags-when-device-orientation-changes)

Comment: No, it's odd. Thanks @Maetschl I'll check out the link :)

Comment: Saying that "doing anything on the update func is a bad idea" is misleading. The comment from Apple's doc just means that you shouldn't be calling it directly since SpriteKit is calling it for you. But for whatever needs to be done at the start of each frame, it's the appropriate place.